# How to use terraform workspace interpolation to separate resources creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

Lets suppose I have dev, uat and prod environment. I wan't to have some modules to be deployed in the dev environment but not in other environment.

I want to put a condition based on the workspace I have but can't figure it out how. Any recommendation would be appreciated.

I tried to use `$(terraform.workspace)` to select 'dev' enviroment but wasn't working.

```
count = $(terraform.workspace) == "dev" ? 1 : 0 and it says
```

which resulted in:

> This character is not used within the language.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `$` sign.

```
count  = terraform.workspace == "dev" ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different styles and two different logics to write this condition.

**Different Styles**

- If `terraform.workspace` is equal to "dev" then create one instance else zero instance.

```
count = "${terraform.workspace}" == "dev" ? 1 : 0
count = terraform.workspace == "dev" ? 1 : 0
```

**Another logic**

- If `terraform.workspace` is **not** equal to "dev" then create zero instance else one instance.

```
count = "${terraform.workspace}" != "dev" ? 0 : 1
count = terraform.workspace != "dev" ? 0 : 1
```